# How to limit number of concurrent tasks executing in a TaskGroup

Tags: ios, swift, async-await

The following function will download image data for assets passed into the function, transforming an array of `PHAsset` to an array of `Data` asynchronously and concurrently using a task group in Swift's async/await.

When called providing for example 100 `PHAsset`s, all tasks are added to the group right away, and thus 100 data download requests are kicked off at the same time. At least in testing - it's my understanding the system can decide how to limit it.

How can you limit the number of concurrent tasks executing at a time in the group? For example in this scenario perhaps I'd like to only allow it to download a maximum of 10 photos at a time rather than all 100 (or 1000) that were provided.

```
func loadImageData(for assets: [PHAsset]) {
    Task {
        do {
            let imagesData = try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: (id: String, data: Data).self) { group in
                for asset in assets {
                    group.addTask {
                        return (id: asset.localIdentifier, data: try await self.imageData(for: asset))
                    }
                }
                
                var dictionary = [String: Data]()
                for try await item in group {
                    dictionary[item.id] = item.data

                    print("Downloaded \(dictionary.count) of \(assets.count)")
                }
                
                return assets.compactMap { dictionary[$0.localIdentifier] }
            }
            
            print("Done")
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

func imageData(for asset: PHAsset) async throws -> Data() {
    //code here makes PHImageManager.requestImageDataAndOrientation play nicely with async/await
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting priority of your added tasks to see if it gives any different results?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is wayt to limit it on TaskGroup. But for my CLI apps, I needed to limit number of simultaneously executed task, so while app runs in background, I still could work with my mac. So I wrtoe [pool drainer](https://github.com/NikolayJuly/drain-work-pool)

Usage:

```
let pool = AsyncOperationsPool<Int>(maxConcurrentOperationCount: 5)
for i in 0..<1024 {
    pool.add { /* some heavy async task */ }
}

for try await i in pool {
  // process result
}
```